# Check if listed fieldnames are in shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I have one main folder and it has multiple sub-folder. Each sub-folder has one shapefile. I want to check some attribute field names like `PLACENAME`, `GNIS_ID`, which are present in all the shapefiles or not. If not present those field name then print the shapefile name.

I have written small code and getting error. I am learning Python.

Code:

```
import arcpy, os, string
rootFolder = 'C:\Y4YK\Muni'
ctr = 1
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootFolder):
    for name in files:
        if name.endwith(".shp):
            feature_class = name
            fiedCheck = ["PLACENAME", "GNIS_ID"]
            fileds = arcpy.ListFields(feature_class)
            fieldName = [f.name for f in fields]
            for field in fieldCheck
                 if filed in filedName:
                    print "Field Exist"
                 else
                    print feature_class
```

Comment: Change `if name.endwith(".shp):` to `if name.endwith(".shp"):`. I mean `".shp` to `".shp"`. Add double quote.

Comment: Backslashes in strings are used to insert special characters (newlines, tabs, etc.) Any of the following will work to represent rootFolder: `r'C:\Y4YK\Muni'`, `'C:\\Y4YK\\Muni'`, or `'C:/Y4YK/Muni'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
import arcpy, os

shapefolder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata'
fields_to_check = ['PLACENAME','GNIS_ID']

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(shapefolder):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.shp'):
            fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(os.path.join(path,name))]
            if any(f not in fields_to_check for f in fields):
                print 'Field(s) are missing for shapefile: {0}'.format(os.path.join(path,name))
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much its works.Thank you so much its works. i need one more help, i want to test all fields of the shape file  which are having null values. if shape files filed have null values then print the shape file name along with field name.

Comment: I have found this code but i am getting confused how to incorporate  with this code fields = dict((f.name, []) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if not f.required)

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc,"","","","")
for row in rows:
    for f in fields.keys():
        fields[f].append(row.getValue(f))

for field, values in fields.iteritems():
    if any(map(lambda s: s is None or not str(s).strip(), values)):
        print 'Field: "{}" has empty values'.format(field)

Comment: @EmtiajHoque nice, please acccept my answer with the checkbox if it solved your problem. I Think you should post that as a new question.